# Не заканчивается программа, не знаю что делать Assembler

Tags: ассемблер, tasm

Работаю в TASM, не знаю что происходит, где то на 3 действии
программа начинается заново и потом не заканчивается.

```
.386
dseg segment use16
array1 dw 40,10,50,5
dseg ends

cseg segment use16
assume cs:cseg, ds:dseg

m1:
mov cx,dseg
mov ds,cx
mov cx, 4                   ;Счетчик 
lea si,ds:array1
call Dure
xor bx,bx 
inc si
inc si
loop Dure                   ; Повторяем пока CX не равно 0
mov ah, 4ch
int 21h
                        ;Начало процедуры
Dure proc
m2:
cmp ds:[si], word ptr 20    ;Сравниваем текущее число с 20
jg short m3                 ;если не подходит то прыгаем на m3
cmp ds:[si], word ptr -20   ;Сравниваем текущее число с -20
jl short m3                 ;если не подходит то прыгаем на m3
mov bx,2730                 ;отображаем в регистре bx если все верно
jmp short m4         
m3:
mov bx,3549                 ;отображаем в регистре bx если не подходит

m4:
ret           
Dure endp           
cseg ends
end m1
end m2
end m3
```

Comment: В `loop` в качестве параметра должна быть указана метка, расположенная, очевидно, после инициализации счетчика, а не имя процедуры.

Comment: @insolor Сделал, как вы сказали, ничего не изменилось((

Comment: В отладчике ходили?

Comment: @insolor, тут уж все равно. В ассемблере метка и функция - это одно и то же (все, куда можно сделать jmp - это метка) Автору: Вы уверены, что всё начинается у Вас сначала? `loop Dure` делает `jmp` на функцию. А `jmp` не кладет в стек адрес возврата. То есть в `ret` неизвестно, куда прыгнет управление

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов да ходил

Comment: @АлексейСаровский да, где то так и начинается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пока что вижу две ошибки:

#### Ошибка №1

Команда `loop Label` более-менее эквивалентна двум командам:

```
dec cx
jnz Label
```

Таким образом, команда `loop Dure` делает переход на процедуру, а не на начало цикла.

Исправить код можно таким образом:

```
m1:
  mov cx,dseg
  mov ds,cx
  mov cx, 4                   ;Счетчик 
  lea si,ds:array1
m_cycle: ; Начало цикла
  call Dure
  xor bx,bx 
  inc si
  inc si
  loop m_cycle                   ; Повторяем пока CX не равно 0
  mov ah, 4ch
  int 21h
```

#### Ошибка №2

Несколько инструкций `end` в конце программы. Должен быть только один `end` именем метки, указывающей на то место, откуда программа начинает работу. В вашем случае это метка `m1`, поэтому нужно оставить только `end m1`.

Больше явных ошибок я не вижу, ничего такого, что может привести к зависанию вроде бы нет. Исправьте указанные проблемы и попробуйте запустить программу под отладчиком.

Comment: Спасибо большое, все работает